# HTML Content gets cropped

Tags: html, css

I have a problem. I created the following page:

```css
#newOrderControl {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px;
    width: min-content;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  
  #newOrderInputFields {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
    column-gap: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
  }
  
  #newOrderInputFields .inputField {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
  }

  
  #newOrderInputFields label {
    flex-shrink: 0;
  }
  
  #newOrderButtons {
    align-self: flex-end;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
  }
  
  #newOrderButtons button {
    float: right;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 2px;
    color: white;
    height: 30px;
    width: auto;
    padding: 0px 15px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 0px 5px;
  }
  
  .btnAll {
    background-color: #6DA0ED;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
  
  #btnTakeProfit {
    background-color: #33AB37;
  }
  
  #btnPlaceOrder {
    background-color: #6DA0ED;
  }
  
  .title {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    color: #1D0F73;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="newOrderControl">
<label class="title">New order</label>
<div id="newOrderInputFields">
    <div class="inputField">
    <label>Action:</label>
    <select id="txtOrderAction">
        <option value="">-</option>
        <option value="Buy">Buy</option>
        <option value="Sell">Sell</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div class="inputField">
    <label>Quantity:</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtOrderQuantity">
    <button class="btnAll" onclick="setAllQuantity()">All</button>
    </div>
    <div class="inputField">
    <label>Target price:</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtOrderTargetPrice">
    </div>
    <div class="inputField">
    <label>Target perc:</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtOrderTargetPerc">
    </div>
    <div class="inputField">
    <label>Coin:</label>
    <select id="txtOrderCoin">
        <option value="">-</option>
        <option value="">SPTF</option>
        <option value="">TLS</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div class="inputField">
    <label>Amount:</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtOrderAmount">
    <button class="btnAll" onclick="setAllAmount()">All</button>
    </div>
    <div class="inputField">
    <label>Limit price:</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtOrderLimitPrice">
    </div>
    <div class="inputField">
    <label>Limit perc:</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtOrderLimitPerc">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="newOrderButtons">
    <button id="btnTakeProfit">Take profit</button>
    <button id="btnPlaceOrder">Place order</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Now with this code I have a few problems:

- The 2 selects (action and coin) don't have an equal width, so they are not aligned perfectly
- When I resize my page everything goes trough each other

I thought I could fix it by setting `width: min-content;` in `#newOrderControl`, but that crops everything trough each other:
[image]

So I tried setting it to auto, but then it uses the entire page:
[image]

How can I keep the positions while resizing the page and give the `#newOrderControl` the width it needs to place everything, without using the entire page?

Comment: Don't use `float` to layout content. Use `flex` instead https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex

Comment: Okay I will, but that doesn't solve the issue

Comment: First problem can be solved using `max-width` and `width` property. For second issue, you need to use media query

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk I would in all honesty don't use headlines like that, but rather a design as seen in Material Design: https://material.io/components/text-fields That would look good AND avoid your problems with elements not aligning on the same row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did this solve the issue? I removed a couple of things. The biggest issues were `width: min-content` and `display: flex` on `#newOrderControl`, and using `margin` instead of `padding`. Margin doesn't work well with grid and flex.

I also removed the float, and all display properties on children of `#newOrderInputFields`, because it didn't seem like they did anything.

Whenever you have problem with CSS, try removing as much code as possible and start again.

As mentioned in the comments. Don't use float in design, unless it's an element that text should flow around.

I didn't focus on fixing the different input field widths. I would probably solve that by using a min-width, as you stated, or use Material Design's suggestion for text fields.

```css
#newOrderControl {
    /* display: flex; */
    display: inline-flex; /* ADDED */
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px;
    /* width: min-content; */
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  
  #newOrderInputFields {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
    column-gap: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
  }
  
  /* #newOrderInputFields .inputField {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
  }*/

  
  /* #newOrderInputFields label {
    flex-shrink: 0;
  }*/
  
  #newOrderButtons {
    align-self: flex-end;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
  }
  
  #newOrderButtons button {
    /*float: right;*/
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 2px;
    color: white;
    height: 30px;
    width: auto;
    padding: 0px 15px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    /* margin: 0px 5px; */
    padding: 0px 5px; /* ADDED */
  }
  
  .btnAll {
    background-color: #6DA0ED;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
  
  #btnTakeProfit {
    background-color: #33AB37;
  }
  
  #btnPlaceOrder {
    background-color: #6DA0ED;
  }
  
  .title {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    color: #1D0F73;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: bold;
    /* margin: 5px; */
    padding: 5px; /* ADDED */
}
```

```html
<div id="newOrderControl">
  <label class="title">New order</label>
  <div id="newOrderInputFields">
    <div class="inputField">
      <label>Action:</label>
      <select id="txtOrderAction">
        <option value="">-</option>
        <option value="Buy">Buy</option>
        <option value="Sell">Sell</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="inputField">
      <label>Quantity:</label>
      <input type="text" id="txtOrderQuantity">
      <button class="btnAll" onclick="setAllQuantity()">All</button>
    </div>
    <div class="inputField">
      <label>Target price:</label>
      <input type="text" id="txtOrderTargetPrice">
    </div>
    <div class="inputField">
      <label>Target perc:</label>
      <input type="text" id="txtOrderTargetPerc">
    </div>
    <div class="inputField">
      <label>Coin:</label>
      <select id="txtOrderCoin">
        <option value="">-</option>
        <option value="">SPTF</option>
        <option value="">TLS</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="inputField">
      <label>Amount:</label>
      <input type="text" id="txtOrderAmount">
      <button class="btnAll" onclick="setAllAmount()">All</button>
    </div>
    <div class="inputField">
      <label>Limit price:</label>
      <input type="text" id="txtOrderLimitPrice">
    </div>
    <div class="inputField">
      <label>Limit perc:</label>
      <input type="text" id="txtOrderLimitPerc">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="newOrderButtons">
    <button id="btnTakeProfit">Take profit</button>
    <button id="btnPlaceOrder">Place order</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're not opposed to using flex and grid together here's another option for you
EDIT to add mobile:

```css
#newOrderControl {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 1px;
  width: min-content;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
}
#newOrderInputFields {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 2em 2em;
  grid-template-columns: 9em 18em 16em 16em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  padding-top: 1em;
}
input {
  width: 10em;
}
select {
  width: 5em;
}
#txtOrderAmount {
  margin-left: 2px;
}
#txtOrderLimitPrice {
  margin-left: 4px;
}
#txtOrderLimitPerc {
  margin-left: 4px;
}
#txtOrderCoin {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
#newOrderButtons {
  align-self: end;
}
#newOrderButtons button {
  float: right;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 2px;
  color: white;
  height: 30px;
  width: auto;
  padding: 0px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 0px 5px;
}
.btnAll {
  background-color: #6da0ed;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 1px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
#btnTakeProfit {
  background-color: #33ab37;
}
#btnPlaceOrder {
  background-color: #6da0ed;
}
.title {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  color: #1d0f73;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 5px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  #newOrderControl {
    width: min-content + 10;
  }
  input {
    width: 5em;
  }
  #newOrderInputFields {
    grid-template-rows: 2em 2em 2em 2em;
    grid-template-columns: 13.5em 13.5em;
  }
  #txtOrderAmount {
    margin-left: 19px;
  }
  #txtOrderLimitPrice {
    margin-left: 2px;
  }
  #txtOrderLimitPerc {
    margin-left: 7px;
  }
  #txtOrderCoin {
    margin-left: 37px;
  }
  #txtOrderTargetPrice {
    margin-left: 5px;
  }
  #txtOrderAction {
    margin-left: 27px;
  }
  #txtOrderQuantity {
    margin-left: 17px;
  }
  #txtOrderTargetPrice {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  #txtOrderTargetPerc {
    margin-left: 4px;
  }
  #Action_Quantity {
    grid-area: 2 / 1 / span 1 / span 1;
  }
  #Action_TrgtPrice {
    grid-area: 3 / 1 / span 1 / span 1;
  }
  #Action_TrgtPerc {
    grid-area: 4 / 1 / span 1 / span 1;
  }
  #newOrderButtons {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="newOrderControl">
  <label class="title">New order</label>
  <div id="newOrderInputFields">
    <div class="inputField">
      <label class="inputLabel">Action:</label>
      <select id="txtOrderAction">
        <option value="">-</option>
        <option value="Buy">Buy</option>
        <option value="Sell">Sell</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="inputField" id="Action_Quantity">
      <label class="inputLabel">Quantity:</label>
      <input type="text" id="txtOrderQuantity">
      <button class="btnAll" onclick="setAllQuantity()">All</button>
    </div>

    <div class="inputField" id="Action_TrgtPrice">
      <label class="inputLabel">Target price:</label>
      <input type="text" id="txtOrderTargetPrice">
    </div>

    <div class="inputField" id="Action_TrgtPerc">
      <label class="inputLabel">Target perc:</label>
      <input type="text" id="txtOrderTargetPerc">
    </div>

    <div class="inputField">
      <label>Coin:</label>
      <select id="txtOrderCoin">
        <option value="">-</option>
        <option value="">SPTF</option>
        <option value="">TLS</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="inputField">
      <label class="inputLabel">Amount:</label>
      <input type="text" id="txtOrderAmount">
      <button class="btnAll" onclick="setAllAmount()">All</button>
    </div>

    <div class="inputField">
      <label class="inputLabel">Limit price:</label>
      <input type="text" id="txtOrderLimitPrice">
    </div>

    <div class="inputField">
      <label class="inputLabel">Limit perc:</label>
      <input type="text" id="txtOrderLimitPerc">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="newOrderButtons">
    <button id="btnTakeProfit">Take profit</button>
    <button id="btnPlaceOrder">Place order</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your result fits my needs more, but it still has 1 problem. The input fields are not aligned with each other. On my mobile the effect is more obvious. The reason for this is that labels can have different lengths

Comment: I'm not seeing any thing being cropped on the drop-down but to make the box wider you can change `select` to `4.5em` or `5em`  here --> `select {
  width: 4.5em;
}`

Comment: If you are going for mobile now I would use media query and re-style it.

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk I would just rearrange the format similar to how I edited it above for smaller screens.